# Revising program to pass original value

Tags: plsql

My task is to revise this program so that before updating the current balance in an account which was the current balance becomes the previous balance.**So for example, if the column "Current Bal" holds a value of 100 and the column "Previous Bal" holds a value of 50...when updated the "previous bal" column will then need to take the value of 100 while a new value is updated into the "current bal" column. When an update is done in place of an insertion, the former current balance should become the previous balance. In the case of an insertion of a new account, the previous balance should be set to zero and the current balance becomes the new balance. This is my code... Can someone point me in the right direction??? Thanks in advance!

```
/*
**  This program modifies the ACCOUNTS table based on instructions
**  stored in the ACTION table.  Each row of the ACTION table
**  contains an account number to act upon, an action to be taken
**  (insert, update, or delete), and an amount to update the
**  account to if the action is not a delete.
**      On an insert, if the account already exists, an update is
**  performed instead.  On an update, if the account does not exist,
**  then the account is created via an insert.  On a delete, if the
**  row does not exist, no alternative action is taken.
**
**
*/
DECLARE
  CURSOR c1 IS
    SELECT account_id, oper_type, new_value FROM action
    ORDER BY time_tag
  FOR UPDATE OF status;
  e_primary_key_error exception;
  PRAGMA EXCEPTION_INIT (e_primary_key_error, -00001);
BEGIN
  FOR acct IN c1 LOOP      -- process each row one at a time
  DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE (ACCT.ACCOUNT_ID);
  acct.oper_type := upper(acct.oper_type);
  /*--------------------------------------------*
   * Process an UPDATE.  If the account to      *
   * be updated doesn't exist, create a new     *
   * account.                                   *
   *--------------------------------------------*/
  IF acct.oper_type = 'U' THEN
     UPDATE accounts SET bal = acct.new_value
            WHERE account_id = acct.account_id;
     IF SQL%NOTFOUND THEN      -- account didn't exist.  Create it.
     INSERT INTO accounts
                VALUES (acct.account_id, acct.new_value);
     UPDATE action SET status =
             'Update:  ID not found.  Value inserted.'
             WHERE CURRENT OF c1;
     ELSE
       UPDATE action SET status = 'Update:  Success.'
             WHERE CURRENT OF c1;
     END IF;
/*----------------------------------------------*
 * Process an INSERT.  If the account already   *
 * exists, do an update of the account          *
 * instead.                                     *
 *----------------------------------------------*/
  ELSIF acct.oper_type = 'I' THEN
     BEGIN
       INSERT INTO accounts
          VALUES (acct.account_id, acct.new_value);
       UPDATE action set status = 'Insert: Success.'
          WHERE CURRENT OF c1;
     EXCEPTION
       WHEN e_primary_key_error THEN      -- account already exists
          UPDATE accounts SET bal = acct.new_value
               WHERE account_id = acct.account_id;
               UPDATE action SET status =
                 'Insert: Acct exists, Primary Key Error. Update instead.'
               WHERE CURRENT OF c1;
     END;
/*----------------------------------------------*
 * Process a DELETE.  If the account doesn't    *
 * exist, set the status field to say that      *
 * the account wasn't found.                    *
 *----------------------------------------------*/
ELSIF acct.oper_type = 'D' THEN
    DELETE FROM accounts
       WHERE account_id = acct.account_id;
    IF SQL%NOTFOUND THEN          -- account didn't exist.
       UPDATE action SET status = 'Delete: ID not found.'
           WHERE CURRENT OF c1;
    ELSE
       UPDATE action SET status = 'Delete: Success.'
           WHERE CURRENT OF c1;
    END IF;
/*-----------------------------------------------*
 * The requested operation is invalid.           *
 *-----------------------------------------------*/
ELSE
    UPDATE action SET status = 'Invalid operation. No action taken.'
           WHERE CURRENT OF c1;
END IF;
END LOOP;
COMMIT;
END;
```

TABLES ARE:

```
CREATE TABLE ACCOUNTS
{ACCOUNT_ID    NUMBER;
PREVIOUS_BAL   NUMBER;
CURRENT_BAL    NUMBER;
}

CREATE TABLE ACTION
{ACCOUNT_ID    NUMBER;
 ORDER_TYPE    CHAR(1);
 NEW_VALUE     NUMBER(11,2);
 STATUS        CHAR(60);
 TIME_TAG      DATE;
}
```

Comment: So you have all this code here.  Did you write any of it?  You don't show any of the table definitions.  What is the specific problem with this code?

Comment: no this is the starting code I was given. I tried editing it a little to see what the procedure would compile but sqlplus just sits there and doesnt do anything. I then tried to just copy the original without any modification (shown above) into sqlplus but again it doesnt do anything. My professor only requires us to incorporate three modifications to the program so I am assuming the original code is correct..but when I copied it into sqlplus it doesnt run. No error messages were shown..

Comment: This is not a procedure.  It is an anonymous PL/SQL block.  Try adding a "/" to the end of your script.  If you are still stuck, then I would suggests to get some help from your professor.

Answer (score 0):

## Troubleshooting Oracle PL/SQL Code Blocks in SQL Plus

The DDL code (table creation scripts) has incorrect syntax.  The columns of the table definitions are separated with semi-colons and will not execute as-is.  That being the case, the procedure will not run, primarily because the objects queried in the SQL statements within will not be found because they weren't created with the ddl code and its incorrect syntax.

Try querying the tables themselves in SQLPlus with commands like:

```
SQL> Describe ACTION
  2> /
```

or maybe a direct query or DML command:

```
SQL> SELECT * FROM ACTION
  2> /
```

What do you observe with this command (above?)

```
SQL> INSERT INTO ACTION(ACCOUNT_ID, ORDER_TYPE, NEW_VALUE, STATUS, TIME_TAG)
  2> VALUES (1, 'I', 100.50, null, sysdate);
  3> COMMIT;
  4> /
```

You seem lost with what to expect from a large block of PL/SQL code because of an unfamiliarity with issuing inputs and receiving results through the SQLPlus command line.

### Reviewing a PL/SQL Anonymous Code Block

Try looking for other discrete query segments or pieces of DML code (i.e., complete insert/update/delete commands) within the block you pasted.  Run them alone by substituting in your own hard-coded values until you are convinced you understand what these parts of the code are doing.

If you are getting an ORA-typed error related to missing objects or tables that do not exist, consider the following:

```
CREATE TABLE ACTION
   {ACCOUNT_ID    NUMBER;
    ORDER_TYPE    CHAR(1);
    NEW_VALUE     NUMBER(11,2);
    STATUS        CHAR(60);
    TIME_TAG      DATE;
   }
```

Should actually read something more like:

```
CREATE TABLE ACTION
   (ACCOUNT_ID    NUMBER,
    ORDER_TYPE    CHAR(1),
    NEW_VALUE     NUMBER(11,2),
    STATUS        CHAR(60),
    TIME_TAG      DATE
   );
```

***Some pointers to look at when working with the code sample:***

1. You should be looking closely at the code for the cursor `c1` defined in the declaration section of your code:

   ```
     CURSOR c1 IS
         SELECT account_id, oper_type, new_value FROM action
         ORDER BY time_tag
     FOR UPDATE OF status;
   ```

   *Hint:  The rest of your PL/SQL code is expecting something to be in this cursor at run time.*
2. The lines reading `DBMS_OUTPUT...` are related to the screen feedback you're looking for.  Try searching for a quick reference on [DBMS_OUTPUT and SQL Plus](https://asktom.oracle.com/pls/asktom/f?p=100:11:0%3a%3a%3a%3aP11_QUESTION_ID:1968769482859) (use my link or find one of your own...)
3. [Oracle PL/SQL Exception Handling](http://psoug.org/reference/exception_handling.html) is another good search term to investigate.  Your professor has already put in a stub/hook in the code that will work well with a PL/SQL exception handler provided there is one put in waiting for it... and if the condition it is watching for is met.

It looks like you've just got started on the problem.  The above ideas should provide some results that will help build a bigger picture of the task at hand... if not already giving away a few clues and answers within.

> I recommend that you give a few of these pointers some consideration... even better, try them out.

*I purposely haven't dived deeper into a fully detailed solution because this is a homework assignment, potentially where the assignment of a grade or credit is involved.*

We're all learners here, but next time come better prepared with stronger evidence that you've attempted the solution beyond a quick cut and paste from the course syllabus.

Additionally, the SQL Plus tips should get you better acquainted with some typical commands and interactions to see the results of code created within the Oracle database environment.

***Best wishes on your initial exploration into Oracle and RDBMS Programming!***